# Renewenvironment of with optional arguments enumerate goes wrong with enumitem (compilation stalls)

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I want to modify the `enumerate` environment (from `enumitem`) to always be passed a certain optional argument. I expected the following code to work, but it always stalls (takes forever).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\ooenumerate\enumerate
\let\endooenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]{%
     \ooenumerate[series=test,#1]%
}{
     \endooenumerate%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item ione 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I'm on

> pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MikTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit)

Comment: `\LetLtxMacro\ooenumerate\enumerate` (requires `\usepackage{letltxmacro}`)